# Laravel route starting with a specific string

Tags: php, routes, laravel-5

I need to create a route with some fixed and dynamic parts. Basically I need to be flexible on the second segment on the url. If the url starts with 'products/test....' then the route has to go to the PageController, all other routes starting with 'products/....' have to go to the ProductController.

```
// Something like this:
Route::any('products/".starts_with($slug, 'test'), [
    'uses' => 'PageController@show'
])->where('slug', '(.*)?');

Route::get('products/{slug}', [
    'uses' => 'ProductController@show'
]);
```

Is this possible in Laravel 5?

Comment: so whats wrong with this routes?

Comment: The 'starts_with($slug, 'test')' part. Not working, ment as an example what I try to achieve.

Comment: can you show example url your trying to achieve here?

Comment: you can give try to `Route::any('products/test/{slug}', ["usage"=>"PageController@show"])`.

Answer (score -1):

In Laravel 5 we use Middleware as helpers for routes. 
There are some examples in the default installation that you can adapt for your code. This is the best approach for this issue.

Comment: Ok, I will dive into that.